# Segmentation Fault on EVP_PKEY_encrypt_init for RSA on OpenSSL 3

Tags: encryption, openssl, rsa

I'm playing around with openssl 3 (in C++), and I'm trying to write a simple program that reads some bytes, creates on the fly RSA secret/public keys, public encrypts, and decrypts.

I'm stuck at `EVP_PKEY_encrypt_init`. At that call I get a segmentation fault. If I run the code trough gdb the `main` returns 5 (still fails, and I'm not sure why).

I'm finding difficult to understand how to actually do the whole application, and I'm mainly basing my exploration on OpenSSL Man3 files. The code is more or less an extrapolation of what I understood of the manual. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I have no idea what. Can you help me?

This is the code, should be MVCE:

```
#define OPENSSL_NO_DEPRECATED
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

constexpr int KEY_BITS = 4096;

void cleanup(EVP_PKEY_CTX * ctx, EVP_PKEY * pkey, unsigned char * encrypted, unsigned char * decrypted) {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    if (ctx) { EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx); }
    if (pkey) { EVP_PKEY_free(pkey); }
    if (encrypted) { OPENSSL_free(encrypted); }
    if (decrypted) { OPENSSL_free(decrypted); }
}


int main(int argc, const char ** argv) {
    EVP_PKEY_CTX * ctx = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY * pkey = NULL;

    if (argc != 2) {
        return 101;
    }

    std::cout << "MESSAGE: " << argv[1]  << std::endl;

    const size_t inlen = strlen(argv[1]);
    size_t outlen = 0;
    size_t doutlen = 0;

    unsigned char * encrypted = NULL;
    unsigned char * decrypted = NULL;

    // Create context
    ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_RSA, NULL);
    if (!ctx) { 
        cleanup(ctx, pkey, encrypted, decrypted);
        return 1;
    }
    // Init key generator
    if (EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(ctx) <= 0) {
        cleanup(ctx, pkey, encrypted, decrypted);
        return 2;
    }

    // Configure key generation
    if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_keygen_bits(ctx, KEY_BITS) <= 0) {
        cleanup(ctx, pkey, encrypted, decrypted);
        return 3;
    }

    // Create keys
    if (EVP_PKEY_keygen(ctx, &pkey) <= 0) {
        cleanup(ctx, pkey, encrypted, decrypted);
        return 4;
    }
    // std::cout << "PRIVATE KEY:" << std::endl;
    // EVP_PKEY_print_private_fp(stdout, pkey, 0, NULL);
    // std::cout << "PUBLIC KEY:" << std::endl;
    // EVP_PKEY_print_public_fp(stdout, pkey, 0, NULL);

    // Init encryption context. 
    if (EVP_PKEY_encrypt_init(ctx) <= 0) { // <-SEGFAULT LINE
       cleanup(ctx, pkey, encrypted, decrypted);
       return 5;
    }

    // Defines padding
    if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING) <= 0) {
        cleanup(ctx, pkey, encrypted, decrypted);
        return 6;
    }

    // Evaluating size for encrypted buffer and encrypting
    if (EVP_PKEY_encrypt(ctx, NULL, &outlen, (const unsigned char *)argv[1], inlen) <= 0) {
        cleanup(ctx, pkey, encrypted, decrypted);
        return 7;
    }

    encrypted = (unsigned char *)OPENSSL_malloc(outlen);
    if (!encrypted) {
        cleanup(ctx, pkey, encrypted, decrypted);
        return 8;
    }

    if (EVP_PKEY_encrypt(ctx, encrypted, &outlen, (const unsigned char *)argv[1], inlen) <= 0) {
        cleanup(ctx, pkey, encrypted, decrypted);
        return 9;
    }

    std::cout << "ENCRYPTED: " << (char *)encrypted << std::endl;

    // Evaluating decryptingsize, allocating buffer and decrypting
    if (EVP_PKEY_decrypt(ctx, NULL, &doutlen, encrypted, outlen) <= 0) {
        cleanup(ctx, pkey, encrypted, decrypted);
        return 17;
    }

    decrypted = (unsigned char *)OPENSSL_malloc(doutlen);
    if (!decrypted) {
        cleanup(ctx, pkey, encrypted, decrypted);
        return 18;
    }

    if (EVP_PKEY_decrypt(ctx, decrypted, &doutlen, encrypted, outlen) <= 0) {
        cleanup(ctx, pkey, encrypted, decrypted);
        return 19;
    }

    std::cout << "DECRYPTED: " << (char *)decrypted << std::endl;
    
    cleanup(ctx, pkey, encrypted, decrypted);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling from command line with:

```
g++ -g -Wextra -Werror test.cc $(pkg-config --cflags openssl) $(pkg-config --libs openssl) -o test; ./test sndlkwndl; echo $?
```

And this is my OpenSSL version

```
OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)
built on: Wed Jan 31 18:43:23 2024 UTC
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64)
compiler: gcc -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -Wa,--noexecstack -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/openssl-l59e1T/openssl-3.0.2=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DOPENSSL_TLS_SECURITY_LEVEL=2 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_BUILDING_OPENSSL -DNDEBUG -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-3"
MODULESDIR: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ossl-modules"
Seeding source: os-specific
CPUINFO: OPENSSL_ia32cap=0x7ffaf3bfffebffff:0x40000000029c6fbf
```

(Installed from Ubuntu 22.04LTS repo, `libssl-dev`)

Main References:

- https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_PKEY_CTX_new.html
- https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_PKEY_decrypt.html
- https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_PKEY_encrypt.html

**Side note**: while writing the question I noticed that I'm missing `EPV_PKEY_decrypt_init` somewhere... But if I can encrypt I'm confident I can understand the remaining part (the fun of exploring).

### Update

The comments I received were on point. The context shall be lightweight and should have a short life (I was missing this concept, thanks @maarten-bodewes). I cannot use the same context for both key generation and encryption and decryption. Better to use a new context for each operation. There are situation in which context can be reused, but I really need to understand deeper the lifetime of the context before and test this concept.

In particular, I followed the suggestion by @topaco and added the following code after code generation and after encryption, using `pkey`:

```
cleanup(ctx, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

ctx = nullptr;
ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(pkey, nullptr);
if (!ctx) {
  cleanup(ctx, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
  return 1000;
}
```

The modification solved the segmentation fault problem.

Furthermore, as I already noted and resuggested by @topaco, I had to initialize decryption for context:

```
if (EVP_PKEY_decrypt_init(ctx) <= 0) {
   cleanup(ctx, pkey, encrypted, decrypted);
   return 5;
}
```

The code compiles, but still does not work. Decrypted string is really different with respect to original message, so I still miss something, even if the problem in the title seems resolved.

As a side note: the suggestion of @Topaco (reusing the same context used for encryption directly in decryption) works (still the decrypted text is incorrect, but I think that is a separated issue).

IMPORTANT NOTE: This link is gold: https://github.com/danbev/learning-openssl a full repository of example on OpenSSL! Thanks @topaco!

Comment: For me, encryption fails if I use the same context for key generation and encryption. If I create a new one for encryption with `EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(pkey, NULL)`, just like [here](https://github.com/danbev/learning-openssl/blob/master/rsa.c#L18), it works. Likewise, also for successful decryption I must apply a new context (which has to be set up analogously to that of encryption).

Comment: Cryptography contexts are both lightweight and stateful. I'd always recommend not sharing or reusing them, at the very least by default. If you have to share anything, share the keys (or rather their references).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - In general, not reusing a context is the safe option, but may not be the most efficient. Libraries often support reinitialization as well (which must not necessarily apply to OpenSSL).

Comment: For decryption, it is sufficient for me to use the encryption context as long as it is reinitialized with `EVP_PKEY_decrypt_init()`. You must of course check whether this works for you as well. The debugger shows that the context used for key generation does not contain the generated key itself, which is (presumably) the reason why reinitialization alone does not work to use this context for encryption as well, but that a new context for encryption must be created with `EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(pkey, NULL)` containing the generated key.

Comment: It's nice that e.g. you could continue calls to CBC for the same message or related things like that. Creating a new context won't be much faster than re-init. If it isn't for semantic reasons I would consider it premature optimization. But yeah, that's my opinion.

Comment: You are both correct, I updated the question. Creating a new context was the key point for avoiding the segfault, stll decryption has incorrect result. I will study a little more. Thanks to you both.

Comment: Maybe you have forgotten the specification of the OAEPadding for decryption. If a newly created context with `EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(pkey, nullptr)` is used for decryption, initialization alone with `EVP_PKEY_decrypt_init()` is not sufficient, but the OAEP padding must also be apecified with `EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding()` (since OAEP is not the default). If, in contrast, the re-initialized encryption context is used for decryption, OAEP is already specified and does not need to be set again.

Comment: @Topaco it was indeed the padding. Thanks!

Comment: @Topaco in order to have it working without recreating a new context (re-using the one for encrypt also in decrypt) I still need to set the padding after `EVP_PKEY_decrypt_init`, otherwise the data is not decrypted correctly. It is like `_init` functions are resetting the padding option.

Comment: This is not the case for me. Reinitializing the encryption context does not change the padding (and all its parameters) for me. This may depend on the platform and/or version. But regardless of whether it works or not, resetting the padding (and its parameters) after reinitialization seems more transparent and therefore neater to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that should be fixed in the original code.

The first one arise from my misunderstanding of OpenSSL context concept.

- Contexts shall be short lived and light, meaning that can be reused only for few selected operations (this is also the main reason behind the segfault). One of the operation in which contexts can be shared is encryption and decryption, **but not key generation and encryption**.
- Padding must be reset after `EVP_PKEY_(encrypt|decrypt)_init` call, since those call seems to reset that option.

The working code requires:

- to destroy the context after key generation and to create a new one for encryption, with the following snippet:

  ```
  cleanup(ctx, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

  ctx = nullptr;
  ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(pkey, nullptr);
  if (!ctx) {
    cleanup(ctx, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    return 1000;
  }
  ```

  The snippet can be **optionally** included also after completing the encryption of the input message. Otherwise the same context can be used for encryption and decryption (must be destroyed after decryption).

- The intialiazation of the decryption context must always include the configuration of the padding. Seems like the `_init` functions nullify the original option:

  ```
  if (EVP_PKEY_decrypt_init(ctx) <= 0) {
     cleanup(ctx, pkey, encrypted, decrypted);
     return 5;
  }

  if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING) <= 0) {
    cleanup(ctx, pkey, encrypted, decrypted);
    return 6;
  }
  ```

With the two snippets the code works as intended. Special thanks to @Topaco and @maarten-bodewes for their support.